# Get sibling and following text of parent element with XPath

Tags: java, xpath

I have the following partial HTML from which I want to get everything after the last *< br >* using [java](/questions/tagged/java)- means the link element and TEXT5 in this example.

```
<td>
  <span>
    <span>TEXT1</span>
  </span>
  <br>
  TEXT2
  <span>TEXT3</span>
  <br>
  <a href=...>TEXT4</a>
  TEXT5
<td>
```

It is relatively easy to get the link element with

```
td/br[last()]/following-sibling::*
```

but is there a way to get TEXT5 as well?

Comment: You could capture all text within <td>, which would give you "TEXT1TEXT2TEXT3TEXT4TEXT5", and then gsub it to remove everything from the frist character until the ent of TEXT4.

For isntance,
library(tidvyverse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you observed, `*` only return elements while you need to return both element node and text node here. You can do so using `node()` instead, which will return any kind of node :

```
td/br[last()]/following-sibling::node()
```

It is also possible to be more specific if you want, for example, you can add predicate to restrict the node type to be either `a` element or text node :

```
td/br[last()]/following-sibling::node()[self::a|self::text()]
```

Despite the XPath expression itself works, it is possible though, that your Java API doesn't support returning mixed type of nodes, I don't know.

Comment: `node()` and `*` do both return the text element TEXT5 as well, but there was an error in my code that ignored it. This I found out while testing your solution, so I accept this as the best answer.